# Using media queries to optimise mobile web experience

Tags: html, css, firefox, jquery-mobile

I'm pretty new to web development and lately I have been playing around with media queries to optimise my web page when scaled down on various resolutions.

I use the responsive design view in Mozilla Firefox to test my website at different screen sizes but I am having a problem when actually coming to view on a mobile device.

As you can see by the two picture I have attached, when viewing on Mozilla Firefox on the same resolution as my phone (for testing) the display looks a lot larger e.g. the font-size seems to be larger than what it actually is when I view the page on my mobile device.

I've tried researching into how to optimise this without having to create seperate CCS sheets for various displays and would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance, Sam.

[image: Mozilla Firefox view]

[image: Mobile view]

Image 1 : Firefox responsive design view 
 
Image 2 : Mobile view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you are missing the viewport declaration?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

If this doesn't work a fiddle might help see what the issue is.